# Decompiling MCP error (version 9.30) returns 'Decompile Failed'

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm currently running 64-bit Windows 10, and I keep getting a decompile issue with MCP.

This is what keeps happening:

```
'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\java" -jar runtime\bin\fernflower.jar -din=1 -rbr=1 -dgs=1 -asc=1 -rsy=1 -iec=1 -jvn=1 -log=WARN "-e=jars\libraries\net/java/jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/lwjgl/lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl-platform-2.9.4-nightly-20150209-natives-windows.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/ibm/icu\icu4j-core-mojang\51.2\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache/httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3.2\httpcore-4.3.2.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache/logging/log4j\log4j-api\2.0-beta9\log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache/commons\commons-lang3\3.3.2\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\net/java/dev/jna\jna\3.4.0\jna-3.4.0.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\net/sf/jopt-simple\jopt-simple\4.6\jopt-simple-4.6.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/google/guava\guava\17.0\guava-17.0.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\oshi-project\oshi-core\1.1\oshi-core-1.1.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache/httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.3\httpclient-4.3.3.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache/commons\commons-compress\1.8.1\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\it/unimi/dsi\fastutil\7.0.12_mojang\fastutil-7.0.12_mojang.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\net/java/dev/jna\platform\3.4.0\platform-3.4.0.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\codecjorbis-20101023.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\soundsystem-20120107.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/lwjgl/lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl_util-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.9\commons-codec-1.9.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\net/java/jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/lwjgl/lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/mojang\realms\1.9.1\realms-1.9.1.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/mojang\authlib\1.5.22\authlib-1.5.22.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/google/code/gson\gson\2.2.4\gson-2.2.4.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/mojang\netty\1.6\netty-1.6.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\com/paulscode\codecwav\20101023\codecwav-20101023.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\net/java/jinput\jinput-platform\2.0.5\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\org/apache/logging/log4j\log4j-core\2.0-beta9\log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar" "-e=jars\libraries\io/netty\netty-all\4.0.23.Final\netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar" temp/minecraft_ff_in.jar temp\src\minecraft' failed : 1
```

"Decompile failed" Any help? I've looked at previous threads on how to fix this by adding java arguments to allow more RAM to MCP, but those so far have not worked for me, they may be outdated methods.

Comment: Is that all it says?  Nothing else?

Comment: Yeah it is. Unless you are talking about this: http://hastebin.com/evetenukay.tex

Answer (score 2):

Solved. After going through possible problems, I had narrowed it down, I had figured out that the JDK was outdated. I ended up installing the newest JDK for my 64-bit system, and now it is decompiling correctly.

Comment: Yea, Minecraft 1.9 (or maybe 1.10) started using some libraries that require at least Java 7; you were using Java 6.